# I am a beiggner in Laravel. How can we fix this?

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner, building a bulletin board using Laravel. 
I got this error:

> Class 'LaravelForum\Http\Controllers\Discussion' not found

```
>

     public function index()
    >     {
    >         
    >         return view('discussions.index', [
    >             'discussions' => Discussion::paginate(5)
    >         ]);
    >         
    >     //    $discussions = Discussion::paginate(5);
    >      
    >     //     return view('discussions.index');
    >  
    >     }
    >  
    >     /**
    >      * Show the form for creating a new resource.
    >      *
    >      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    >      */
    >     public function create()
    >     {
    >         //
    >         return view('discussions.create');
    >     }
    >  
    >     /**
    > Arguments
    > "Class 'LaravelForum\Http\Controllers\Discussion' not found"
```

This is the content of the file in question:
C:\laravel-apps\bulletin-board\app\Http\Controllers\DiscussionsController.php

```
<?php

namespace LaravelForum\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use LaravelForum\Http\Requests\CreateDiscussionRequest;

class DiscussionsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->only(['create', 'store']);
    }             

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */

    public function index()
    {

        return view('discussions.index', [
            'discussions' => Discussion::paginate(5)
        ]);

    //    $discussions = Discussion::paginate(5);

    //     return view('discussions.index');

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('discussions.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(CreateDiscussionRequest $request)
    {
        //
        auth()->user()->discussions()->create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'content' => $request->content,
            'channel_id' => $request->channel,
            'slug' => str_slug($request->title),
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'Discussin posted .');

        return redirect()->route('discussion.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

C:\laravel-apps\bulletin-board\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace LaravelForum\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could fix this code.

Comment: Please update the title of this post to reflect the actual issue you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **DiscussionsController** add this line at the use section.

```
use LaravelForum\Discussion;
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in Your **DiscussionsController**

```
use LaravelForum\Discussion;
```